# Stampy variations on STOMP protocol?

Tags: java, client, rabbitmq, stomp

I'm attempting to use the Java STOMP client library [Stampy](http://mrstampy.github.io/Stampy/) to connect to RabbitMQ-Web-STOMP.

The Stampy examples have two reference implementations - Mina and Netty.

Are either of these correct to use with RabbitMQ or do I have to implement another RI for RabbitMQ?

Comment: I would hope that _any_ reference implementation of a STOMP client is correct to use against any STOMP server.

Comment: RabbitMQ supports STOMP. So any implementation of `stampy` should work.

Comment: @marko-topolnik That's what I thought, too.  I thought `stampy` *was* the reference implementation.  Yet the `stampy` website lists a "client-server-RI" for each, and the client examples only offer Mina or Netty.  No de-facto client appears to be offered.  It makes me wonder what stampy is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @marko-topolnik commented, a reference implementation is required, but there are two choices.  Both appear to function with my MQ server RabbitMQ.  Even though they are different implementations, they behave identically in relation to the protocol.

I still don't understand why they can't be included with Stampy, tho.